# spark: row to element

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

New to Spark.

I'd like to do some transformation on the "wordList" column of a spark DataFrame, df, of the type `org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: string, wordList: array<string>]`.

I use dataBricks. df looks like:

```
+--------------------+--------------------+
|                  id|            wordList|
+--------------------+--------------------+
|08b0a9b6-3b9a-47a...|                 [a]|
|23c2ef79-8dce-4ad...|[ag, adfg, asdfgg...|
|26a7682f-2ce6-4eb...|[ghe, gener, ghee...|
|2ab530b5-04bc-463...|[bap, pemm, pava,...|
+--------------------+--------------------+
```

More specifically, I have defined a function shrinkList(ol: List[String]): List[String] that takes a list and returns a shorter list, and would like to apply it on the wordList column. The question is, how do I convert the row to a list?

`df.select("wordList").map(t => shrinkList(t(1)))` give the error: `type mismatch;
 found   : Any
 required: List[String]`

Also, I'm not sure about "t(1)" here. I'd rather use the column name instead of the index, in case the order of the columns change in the future. But I can't seem to make t$"wordList" or t.wordList or t("wordList") work. So instead of using t(1), what selector can I use to select the "wordList" column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df.select("wordList").map(t => shrinkList(t.getSeq[String](0).toList))
```

or

```
df.select("wordList").map(t => shrinkList(t.getAs[Seq[String]]("wordList").toList))
```

Comment: Thanks @LostInOverflow. My databricks just died and I can't try it now, but will try it when it works again. Question: instead of using "1", can I use the column name in some way?

Comment: Like this  `getAs[Seq[String]]("some_name").toList` I think.

Comment: the answer I tried gave error: `type mismatch;
 found   : java.util.List[String]
 required: scala.collection.immutable.List[String]`. Your code in the comment works though. Do you want to edit the code in your original answer, keeping the "(1)", as an alternative correct answer, so that I can accept it?

Comment: Also, I now have an RDD after performing the .map. I usually use .toDF() to turn it into a dataFrame again, but in this case it doesn't work. The error is `java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.sql.types.ArrayType cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType`. Do you know why?